# Returning user password expiry date - Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm working on a command to pull users and the date/time that their password will expire.  Trying to make it look somewhat decent.  I feel like this should work, but it's not working as planned.  Can someone with fresh eyes take a look and let me know what I did incorrectly?

`Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | Select-Object -Property "Displayname", {Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}`

Comment: What do you mean with look somewhat decent? You could replace the Select-Object line with fl (full list) so it is readable, but may be lots of text.

Comment: I don't know why I added that, it doesn't need to look right.  But right now this isn't functional.  The names don't populate, I just see the names on the left and the command as the header on the right, some syntax I'm not catching:



`Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, but you've missed a single character.

You need to turn:

```
{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```

into a hash table:

```
@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```

Just that one little `@` symbol is all you need.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew it was something small like that.  For bonus points:  What does the @ do?

Comment: It forces the expression to be evaluated as an array. See here for more detail: http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html

Comment: @( ) is an array and @{ } is a hash table: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/PowerShell/Arrays_and_Hash_Tables